# How to organize code for unit testing BDD using Mocha Chai?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, bdd, mocha.js, chai

I trying unit testing using Mocha/Chai using BDD style. Not sure where to start. Following is what the core code structure is. Assuming that getTemplates is an ajax call, how do I the different stages of an application. For i.e. before hitting sh.setTemplates() in init function, it has go through few conditions. How to unit test those conditions?

```
// Javascript     
function myFunc(id){
var mf = this;
mf.id = id;
mf.init = function(){return init()};
mf.isIdValid = function(){return isIdValid()};
mf.setTemplates = function(){return setTemplates};
mf.getTemplates = function(){return getTemplates};

// Init
mf.init();


///////////////////////
function init(){

    if(!id){
        return false;
    }


    if(!sh.isIdValid()){
        return false;
    }

    sh.setTemplates();
}


///////////////////////
function setTemplates(){
    getTemplates(function(callBackTemplate){
        if(!callbackTemplate){
            return false;
        }

        // inject to dom
    });
}

///////////////////////
// Async call
function getTemplates(){

    return '<div>Test</div>';
}
}



///////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////
TEST JS Mocha/Chai

var expect = chai.expect;

describe('myFunc Class', function(){
var mf;

before(function(){
    mf = new myFunc(1);
});


describe('mf.init()', function(){

    it('should not result false', function(){
        var result = mf.init();
        expect(result).to.not.equal(false);
    });


});
```

Comment: good luck, I've been hitting my head against the wall on the same question with BDD.  If I figure it out I'll reply with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> How to unit test those conditions?

Use the following process:

- Create a branch function
- Put the assertion in the branch function
- Use the variant as an argument
- Call it once with a truthy value
- Call it again with a falsy value

**References**

- [BDD and Fluent Assertions](http://wakaleo.com/index.php/resources/articles/bdd-and-fluent-assertions)
- [Eclipse Orion: Running the Tests](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Orion/Running_the_tests)